# Is Orience on Gran-Pulse somewhere?

Tags: final-fantasy

*Final Fantasy Type-0* is set in Orience however it seems to be connected with *Final Fantasy XIII* as ultimately the world is being manipulated by  fal'Cie in the forms of

- each nation's Crystal being a fal'Cie (as the Crystals can brand people l'Cie)
- > Arecia Al-Rashia who created the Crystals and a servant of the fal'Cie Pulse
- > Gala, servant of the fal'Cie Lindzei who leads the Rursan Army for Tempus Finis
- > Diva, a neutral observer who i don't know who she serves

and their goal is obviously to open Etro's gate as per the will of Bhunivelze .

since these fal'Cie seems to have came from Pulse or Lindzei and more or less going after the the same end goal Pulse's and Lindzei's fal'Cie on Gran-Pulse and Cocoon were after, does this mean that Orience is somewhere on Gran-Pulse? or is it another artificial world like Cocoon or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orience in Final Fantasy Type-0 does not reside on Gran-Pulse from Final Fantasy XIII.

The commonalities that are seen between Final Fantasy Type-0 and Final Fantasy XIII is due to both games being apart of the [Fabula Nova Crystallis](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Fabula_Nova_Crystallis:_Final_Fantasy) series. While they share common mythology, they are do not exist within the same universe. This was explained during the Fabula Nova Crystallis' announcement in 2006

> FABULA NOVA CRYSTALLIS, defined in Latin as "the new tale of the crystal," is made up of several different titles based on variations of the FINAL FANTASY XIII universe. However, while each title in the project features different characters, different worlds, and different stories, all are ultimately based on and expand upon a common mythos. 
>   <sub>[SQUARE ENIX UNVEILS THE NEXT GENERATION OF FINAL FANTASY](http://www.square-enix.com/na/company/press/2006/0508_1/)</sub>

Additional, the Crystals we see in Final Fantasy Type 0 may be considered Fal'Cie and posses similar roles, they are not quite the same as the Fal'Cie we see in Final Fantasy XIII. In an interviewer with the director<sup>1</sup>, in regards to the mythology, it was stated the Crystals found in Final Fantasy Type 0 are merely equivalent to Fal'Cie.

> In an interview found in Final Fantasy Type-0 Artwork Book: Secret Vermillion History, director Hajime Tabata said the Crystals have a limited Will of their own and, in terms of the Fabula Nova Crystallis mythology, are equivalent to the fal'Cie of Final Fantasy XIII (and were initially referred to as fal'Cie)
>   <sup>[Falcie](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Fal%27Cie#Final_Fantasy_Type-0)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> [Translated version of interview](https://web.archive.org/web/20140227212146/http://type0.haloandwingsstudio.com/tabata/)